# Problems with Tkinter window crashing in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, tkinter

I've been developing a chatbot sort of program with tkinter and sockets, and I've had problems integrating Tkinter with the chatbot system, after clicking the "Ask" button, the tkinter window stops responding.

Code for the Client:

`

```
import socket, threading, time
import tkinter as tk

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = '25.65.227.4'
port = 10001

window = tk.Tk()

window.geometry('800x400+20+20')

window.title('Client')

labelBot = tk.Label(window, text='')
labelBot.config(font='Decker')
labelBot.place(x = 10, y = 10)

e1 = tk.Entry(window)
e1.config(font='Decker')
e1.place(x=50, y=350)

photo = tk.PhotoImage(file="Aldenv1.gif")

labelPic = tk.Label(image=photo)
labelPic.place(x=450, y=10)

s.connect((host, int(port)))
print('connected to server')

labelBot['text'] = 'Connected to Server'

def Main():
    while True:

        data = s.recv(2048).decode('utf-8')
        labelBot['text'] = ''
        labelBot['text'] = data

        if not data:
            break

def bt_click():
    answer = e1.get().encode('utf-8')
    s.send(answer)
    Main()

bt = tk.Button(window, text='Ask', command=bt_click)
bt.config(font='Decker')
bt.place(x=400, y=350)
window.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()`
```

I tried doing all sorts of things but I haven't managed to solve this crash

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you examined the value of `data` on every iteration of the loop to make sure it's what you think it is?  Are you aware that tkinter is single-threaded, so while the `while` loop is running, it is unable to respond to events?

Comment: Thanks, I was not paying atention to that while loop, that was causing the problem!